# Why do I keep getting errors when I try to install PySide2 on windows PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I have been trying to install `PySide2` on my PC (`Windows 10 64bits`) with `Python 3.8` installed, but I keep getting errors every time.

I used the command `pip install PySide2`. It is not working for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Error:**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyside2
```

Comment: no issue in `windows 10 64 bits` with `python 3.7.3`

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE**

Since the time of writing above answer, a new version of `pyside2` was released and `pip install` should now be able to find a `whl` for `pyside2` if you have `python 3.8`. The same issue can still arise with newer python versions for which pyside has no compatible whl file released. If you see the same issue as OP, check your python version and the avaialable files on pypi.org carefully

**Original Answer**

If you check the available files on the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/#files), you will see that there are only wheels for `cp35.cp36.cp37` so python 3.5 to 3.7, no files for 3.8. That is why `pip` cannot find a version, since there is no compatible version on `pypi`.

There is also no python 3.8 release on the [qt website](http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.12/latest/pyside2/)

Now you have two options:

1. Try installing from source by following the official [docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted) (I would not recommend this for a beginner)
2. Uninstall python 3.8 and install 3.7 instead or use a virtual environment with python 3.7 (I would recommend this, since you most likely don't rely on the difference between python 3.8 and 3.7)

Comment: PySide2 version 5.14 (which supports Python 3.8) is iminent.  See [this bugfix](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-939?focusedCommentId=489055&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-489055).

Comment: @florisla you are correct, I have added it to my answer

Comment: desn't work on my Raspberry with Python 3.7.2; same error although there should be a wheel for that version

Comment: @mep no, there are no wheels for arm (which is the architecture raspberries are based on, right?) on pypi, only x64 and x86 based systems

Comment: Oh, it actually is possible. See this thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/112813/installing-pyside2-on-raspberry-pi <- worked surprisingly good

Comment: @mep I didn't want to imply that it is not possible, just that you will not find whl files on pypi to install pyside

Comment: With the release of Python 3.11 it's disappointing there appears to be no community packaging pyside2 for easy use. This is not going to. help its adoption, which is a shame when you consider the work that's gone into it.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally for anyone trying to install this on Raspbian (maybe also other Linux
systems):

You can install PySide2 without pip wheel using the following command

```
$sudo apt-get install python3-pyside2.qt3dcore python3-pyside2.qt3dinput python3-pyside2.qt3dlogic python3-pyside2.qt3drender python3-pyside2.qtcharts python3-pyside2.qtconcurrent python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qthelp python3-pyside2.qtlocation python3-pyside2.qtmultimedia python3-pyside2.qtmultimediawidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtpositioning python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtqml python3-pyside2.qtquick python3-pyside2.qtquickwidgets python3-pyside2.qtscript python3-pyside2.qtscripttools python3-pyside2.qtsensors python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qttest python3-pyside2.qttexttospeech python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwebchannel python3-pyside2.qtwebsockets python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtx11extras python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyside2uic
```

Should include all standard Qt functionality. I was able to run my app - it worked surprisingly well.

Just in case - I came by because I couldn't install it via pip on Raspbian.

If you use ArchLinux on your Raspberry Pi, a working wheel should be available though.
See this [thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/112813/installing-pyside2-on-raspberry-pi) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.14 now available, supports cp38, see: http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.14/latest/pyside2/

Answer (score -2):

Install python from the official website: **https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/** then added from Python interpreters.

[image]

Once did it, just need to search pyside2 and install package or from the terminal type: `pip install pyside2`

[image]

[image]