# ModuleNotFoundErrer: PySide2 installation problems

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, pyside2

I want to run a project which invovles PySide2 using Visual Studios. I have installed it using

```
pip install PySide2
```

and the installation worked. But if I want to run my program using import PySide2 I still get the error message:
No module named 'PySide2'. I'm an absolute beginner so maybe you can give me some hints, what I may forgot or what I have to do here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743664/why-do-i-keep-getting-errors-when-i-try-to-install-pyside2-on-windows-pc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I keep getting errors when I try to install PySide2 on windows PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743664/why-do-i-keep-getting-errors-when-i-try-to-install-pyside2-on-windows-pc)

Comment: This question is about the installation of PySide2, which worked properly for me. I just have issues importing PySide2 inside a program since it shows me the ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Do you have still a deprecated Python 2 package installed on your machine? If so, you would have to use pip3 instead of pip to install PySide, because with pip the Python 2.7 Version would be installed. That would not be recognized as a working installation by Python 3.

Comment: I used the pip3 installation and I think it worked. But now I get the message: "
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found."
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Reinstalling doesn't help either. Do you have an idea what to do now?

Comment: Are you using a venv or some specific environment/installation like conda?